# Use awk to change timestamp on column from the ISO 8601 format

Tags: awk, timestamps

I have an output like this:

```
echo "$i"
**@timestamp:** `2023-01-18T15:08:36.698Z`
```

I would like to output this in `awk` and make it look like this:

`Wed 18 Jan 2023 06:50:38 PM EST`

Here's what I tried so far:

```
echo "$i" | awk -F'`' '{print $1, "`"strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T", $2)"`"}'
**@timestamp:**  `1969-12-31 19:33:43`
```

Not sure why it's showing 1969... Any idea?

The date command can detect and fix the format perfectly:

```
date -d $(echo "$i" | awk -F'`' '{print $2}')
Wed 18 Jan 2023 10:08:36 AM EST
```

Why can't awk?

Comment: Assuming you are using GNU awk, the second argument of `strftime` needs to be *"in the same format as the value returned by the systime() function"* (i.e. Unix epoch time, at least on POSIX systems). You may find the [mktime](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-mktime_0028_0029-function-_0028gawk_0029) function helpful.

Comment: In particular, for the string "2023-01..." awk is using the numeric prefix part 2023 as the number of seconds after 1970-01-01T00:00 _UTC_, and in your timezone (apparently UTC-5 which might be US EST) that is 19:33:43 on the previous day.

Answer (score 2):

As has already been pointed out in comments, you can't assume that any other tools time functions will have the same functionality as GNU `date`. Here's how to do what you appear to be trying to do using GNU awk's time functions:

```
$ TZ='EST' awk -F'`' '{print strftime("%a %d %b %Y %T %Z",mktime(gensub(/[^0-9]/," ","g",$2),1))}' file
Wed 18 Jan 2023 10:08:36 EST
```

or if what you really want output is what your code was attempting to do:

```
$ TZ='EST' awk -F'`' '{print strftime("%F %T %Z",mktime(gensub(/[^0-9]/," ","g",$2),1))}' file
2023-01-18 10:08:36 EST
```